# how to add multiple textfields to same indexpath.row in ios 8

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uistoryboard, dynamic-allocation

i want to create an 10 text field on same cell index path how can i do that , get values from them and i want to do this dynamically in storyboard can any one suggest me how can i do this.

```
if (cell != nil) {

    cell = [[tableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    for (int i=indexPath.row ;i< [self.dataArray count];i++) {
        UITextField *valueTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,10,88,21)];
        valueTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
        [valueTextField borderStyle];
        valueTextField.backgroundColor =[UIColor grayColor];
        valueTextField.delegate = self;
        valueTextField.placeholder=@"Placeholder";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:valueTextField];


        cell.editingAccessoryType = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create dynamic frames and do that.